# I want to publish Excel 2013 Power Pivot tables with individual sales data. What options do I have?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to publish interactive pivot tables prepared in Excel 2013 Power Pivot. Spreadsheets contain confidential sales data based on the ODBC data connection. Each employee (viewer of the report) should only see their numbers and should not have the ability to download spreadsheet or raw table data.

What options do I have to achieve such a goal besides installing SharePoint on-site?

Comment: Questions. Where are you planning to publish the workbook? And are you saying that you want to implement row level security? Because this isn't available with powerpivot.

Comment: I meant something like predefined filters or slicers. So the user A has only the ability to see report with "User: A" filter.

Comment: In that case I think you should produce a report per filtered set.